# Laravel 5.2: Cannot call constructor

Tags: php, constructor, controller, laravel-routing, laravel-5

i have some small problem, but i cannot find it out. I have removed from the routes.php the middleweare routes for my admin section. I want this check to be made in one Controller class, which will be extended from all my Admin Controllers.

This is this controller class:

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

public function __constuct() {
    $this->middleware('admin');

}
```

}

Here is one of my Admin Controllers:

```
class AnalysesController extends Controller {

protected $news;
protected $locales;
const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 20;

public function __construct(Analyses $news) {
    $this->news = $news;
    $this->locales = get_locales();
    parent::__construct();
}
```

}

Unfortunately when i call parent::__construct() i get an error: Cannot call constructor

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: This topic should be closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in __constuct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending a custom controller you should call the parent constructor, otherwise you don't need to do so. Make sure your current controller extends from your custom controller in the the class definition.

Answer (score -1):

I would say you have to define an empty construct at Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
}
```

And who extends from Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //...
}
```